# How find shortest path in transport connection by using Cypher query (neo4j) over GTFS data?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, shortest-path, gtfs

I am new in neo4j, I created a graph following this [steps](http://blog.bruggen.com/2015/11/loading-general-transport-feed-spec.html), based on a data model from GTFS. I would like to find all the shortest indirect routes in the graph (with transfers).
[Data model of graph database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es1oN.png) contains 4 entities: Route, Trip, Stop, Stoptime. Here is a screenshot of [db.scheme()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrobf.png).

Based on [query](https://gist.github.com/rvanbruggen/9f6efa3f426ee6ce724f) which wrote Bruggen, I modified it for my use:

```
MATCH 
(from:Stop {code:'VBR'})--(st_from:Stoptime),
(to:Stop {code:'VIR'})--(st_to:Stoptime),
p1=((st_from)-[:PRECEDES*]->(st_midway_arr:Stoptime)),
(st_midway_arr)--(midway:Stop),
(midway)--(st_midway_dep:Stoptime),
p2=((st_midway_dep)-[:PRECEDES*]->(st_to))
WHERE
st_from.departure_time > '00:00'
AND st_from.departure_time < '23:00'
AND st_midway_arr.arrival_time > st_from.departure_time
AND st_midway_dep.departure_time > st_midway_arr.arrival_time
AND st_to.arrival_time > st_midway_dep.departure_time
RETURN
from,st_from,to,st_to,p1,p2,midway
order by (st_to.arrival_time_int-st_from.departure_time_int) ASC
limit 1;
```

This query is not using the shortest path, and it **takes in average 30s to find a path, but the output of the query is good**.

So I tried to write another query, with method allshortestpaths, it really fast (0,3s). But it returns me also trips which run in a different direction (VIR -> VBR)... another problem is the timing od that connection.

**Could you help me, how to access to the transfer node (Station) when I am using allshortestpath method?** I want to write a condition for timing and stop_sequence to be sure that's the right direction.

```
match (from:Stop {code:'VBR'}),(to:Stop {code:'VIR'})
with from,to
match p = allshortestpaths((from)-[*]-(to))
where NONE (x in relationships(p) where type(x)="OPERATES")
return p
limit 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
match (from:Stop {code:'VBR'}),(to:Stop {code:'VIR'})
with from,to
match p = allshortestpaths((from)-[*]->(to)) // here you needed you give the direction to make sure paths are from 'VBR' to 'VIR'
where NONE (x in relationships(p) where type(x)="OPERATES")
return p
limit 10;
```

Next , if you want to see the nodes in the path , then you can use the nodes(p)

```
match (from:Stop {code:'VBR'}),(to:Stop {code:'VIR'})
with from,to
match p = allshortestpaths((from)-[*]->(to)) 
where NONE (x in relationships(p) where type(x)="OPERATES")
AND ALL(node in nodes WHERE node = from OR node = to OR YOUR CONDTION ON TRANSFER NODE)
limit 10
```

Comment: To your comment of the query, I am not able to write the condition of the direction because I don’t know the middle node. (Transfer).  

The condition of direction should look like this, but I don’t know how to access to that “middle_node”.  
`(from:Stop {code:'VBR'})--(st_from:Stoptime),
(to:Stop {code:'VIR'})--(st_to:Stoptime),
WHERE 
st_from.stop_sequence > (middlenode: Stoptime {stop_sequence})
AND 
(middlenode: Stoptime {stop_sequence}) < st_to.stop_sequence`

Comment: hi , you can delete my comment and run the query .. it works and gives only in the paths in the direction you need . I have already mentioned the direction inside allShortestPaths query wich you didnt earlier and thats why you got opposite direction paths too

Comment: Oh, sorry I understand right now, but it doesn't work print screen with an output of your query (https://imgur.com/a/BXC62Qq). My query without direction (https://imgur.com/vc1sm9Q).